# Constraint layout guidelines

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to set left and right padding of the text block using constraint layout guidelines. I want 11% padding with the following code on both sides. However, when I try to set the paddings it is not reflecting. When I only use either left or right then it is showing, but using both left and right guidelines on text view the padding is not reflecting.

Here is the code

```
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/centredIconLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/gothamggm_bold"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/title_long"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="9sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/body"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/gothamssm_book"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="9sp"
                    android:text="@string/content_large"
                    android:textColor="@color/body_grey"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                    />

                <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.11" />

                <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.89" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the blue print where both text views (included in @+id/contentLayout) are below image view
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem is in width of textview**. You have set it to `wrap_content`. This is creating the problem. just change it to `match_constraints` in layout editor or set width to `0dp` in xml code manually and all will work fine.

Comment: hi, I tried using start and End instead of left and right. But still same result.

Comment: Ok, sorry for this but i have copied your code and tried to find problem and i caught it. there is a mistake in setting width of textview. set width to `match_constrains` and all will be good. @AP6